# I need to generate the CSS for my plugin from a function, how do i map a request to a function in the front-end?

Tags: plugins, css, urls

I'm generating my CSS dinamically in a function using a link like this

```
<link id="www-core-css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://wordpress/myplugin/theme-css-loader.php?v=1" />
```

and i was wondering what approach to take. I could either point the href to a file like `http://wordpress/myplugin/theme-css-loader.php?v=1` or i could try to map a request to a function `http://mysite.com/wordpress/?requested_page=myplugin_theme_css_loader&v=1` but i don't know how to that in the frontend ( in the backend i would add a page with add_menu_page and then remove the page with remove_menu_page and the url would still be callable.
Do you know how i could map the url request to a function and does it make sense?
Requiring the file seems to have far less overhead to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is forked from something I wrote for a similar requirement.

```
empty( $_GET['my-css-var'] ) || add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'wpse_59089_css' );
function wpse_59089_css()
{       
    header( 'Content-Type: text/css' );

    // Aggressive caching to save future requests from the same client.
    $etag = '"' . md5( __FILE__ . $_GET['my-css-var'] ) . '"';

    header( 'ETag: ' . $etag );
    header( 'Expires: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + 31536000 ) . ' GMT' );
    header( 'Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000' );

    if ( empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] ) || $etag != stripslashes( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] ) ) {
        // Set all your variables here.
        $my_height = 100;

        // Render your CSS with a heredoc!
        $content = <<<CSS
#my_id {
    height: $my_height;
}
CSS;

        header( 'Content-Length: ' . strlen( $content ) );
        echo $content;

    } else {
        // Not modified!
        status_header( 304 );
    }

    // We're done!
    exit;
}
```

And the resource link would simply be:

> http://example.com/?my-css-var=20120719_or_static_hash.css

Whenever the CSS was changed (typically after a settings update), change the datestamp/hash in the URL to force-refresh.

If you've switched etags off at the server level, you'll need to resort to sending and checking "last modified" instead.

**Update:**

> Don't use a link. Extra http requests are evil. Put your dynamic CSS inline. Really. Even google recommends it.

It all depends. Unless the CSS weighs in tiny, or it's only for a one-off page with low repeat visits, then yeah, inline might be the way to go.

But an aggressively cached external stylesheet will only trigger a request on first access (for the large majority of clients*).

Every new visitor to the site will have to download the CSS one way or another. But inline styles are sent for every subsequent view, whereas the external will hit the local cache.

Take a 1000 visitors, 10 hits each, 500 bytes of CSS. Inline will fatten up the bandwidth an additional ~4MB**. Might not seem much, but bump the CSS size, or the hits per visitor, and it'll continue to creep.

Like I said to start with, it all depends! How large is the CSS? Where is it used? 
Do you have a high ratio of new to loyal visitors? (*Is most of your audience behind a proxy?) (**Are you implementing "Not Modified" on your HTML?)

I guess the point I'm making is that "HTTP requests are evil" isn't gospel, even if it was spouted from the mouth of Google ;)

I'm still of the opinion that anything more than a few lines belongs in an external stylesheet, coupled with a tight set of caching rules, but that suits me, not everyone!

Comment: Actually i'm working on a plugin so i would have to make some checks to see if etags are on or off. Do you think that there is no performance gain in pointing to a single file?So that i do not have to bootstrap Wordpress just to grab the CSS?

Comment: `Do you think that there is no performance gain in pointing to a single file?` None whatsoever. And in fact, by hooking onto `plugins_loaded`, you're saving further processing that would occur if you simply used something like `include '../../../wp-load.php'` (not to mention loading WP yourself is highly inadvisable).

Comment: Don't use a link. Extra http requests are evil. Put your dynamic CSS inline. Really. Even google recommends it.

Comment: @Otto Check out my comments in my revision.

Comment: And I'm not sure my answer deserves a downvote. I've provided a solution the OP was specifically asking for - the debate of using external CSS should be a sidenote to the problem at hand.

Comment: @Otto i totally agrre with the answer provided here, the solution is to get caching right, not putting 4.000 CSS lines inline. And this would be true even with 500 lines of CSS.

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti: If you're dynamically generating 500 or more lines of CSS, then you've already done something horribly wrong with your design.

Comment: @Otto maybe it's because i didn't explain fully my problem :). I generate my CSS with less, and i'm giving to the end user the possibility to change the value of some variables. After the variables are changed, i recompile the Css and store it somewhere ( APC if present, file-system or db ) and so i must generate the CSS in the way i wrote in my question. So it's 4.000 lines of CSS. Do you have a better way to do this?

Comment: I would recommend not using less to begin with (I don't like less), but mainly I would suggest that only the variable pieces should be variable. CSS = *Cascading* style sheets. You should have one static unchanging CSS file, and then override the specific variable pieces of it in the document itself by using more specific rules. That's what the "cascading" part means. Why are you recompiling the whole friggin' document when only a small part of it (hopefully) is actually variable? Just include the variable parts elsewhere, leave the static parts static.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm generating my CSS dinamically in a function...

If so, great! You should just need to hook the output of that function into the `'wp_print_scripts'` action hook, like so:

```
function wpse59089_dynamic_css() {
    ?>
<style type="text/css">
<?php
// Dynamic CSS goes here
?>
</style>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpse59089_dynamic_css' );
```

Comment: Agree with this answer, but I'd use the wp_head hook instead. No particular reason, I just think it's clearer.

Comment: @Otto but in this way i couldn't cache the CSS, right?

Comment: Nor should you. How much CSS are you talking about here? If it's more than 20 lines, you should re-evaluate what you're doing to begin with. Dynamic CSS should be generated in small batches only. There's no sane reason to do more.

Comment: @otto Why not? What if it's a theme with a large choice of variating options? And rather than output all these overrides in the `<head />`, generate one single, optimized stylesheet? I've done this in the past & had no problems with performance (though I generated & saved it as a physical file). I agree it's not common practice, and inline still remains ideal for small snippets, but I just don't understand the flat-out objection to this technique.

Comment: This really starts to get outside the scope of *WordPress*, and into web development in general, but in almost all cases, inline stylesheets in the HTML head are faster and more efficient overall than any other method of injecting CSS.

Comment: @ChipBennett But that's just such a blanket statement! Yes, they're great for small changes & overrides, but for large-scale variable CSS, generating a standalone, cacheable stylesheet will beat them on bandwidth & successive requests. Sorry, I just had to get that out my system; you're right in saying we're verging off-topic - perhaps we should continue this discussion on SO ;)

Comment: @TheDeadMedic rendered HTML pages are equally cacheable. :) FYI, it looks like [SO has already covered this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553074/internal-vs-external-css)...

Comment: Thanks for the link! True, but it's harder to apply aggressive client-side caching on HTML since (typically) there are so many elements that change from page to page, user to user.

Comment: The words "large-scale variable CSS" are a contradiction in terms. Such a thing should not exist. If you have done this, then you have done it wrong to begin with. The whole point of CSS is to define your styles in a semantic fashion, across a wide range of the site. Generating large amounts of CSS dynamically is essentially missing the point of CSS to begin with by not understanding what "cascading" means.

Comment: To put it another way, your "options" most likely should be altering your HTML's classes and such, not altering "large" amounts of CSS. If you're giving extreme control over the details of the site at the CSS level (like Weaver), then it is my considered opinion that you're doing it wrong and making it more complex than it needs to be for your users.

Comment: I think we'll just agree to disagree ;)